# Build with Boost.build and link against boost

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, boost-build

As I am starting a project with boost lib, it seems my set-up isn't working :

main.cpp :

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
    return 0;
}
```

Jamfile :

```
exe node
: main.cpp ;
```

`bjam` will produce :

```
...found 30 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
gcc.compile.c++ bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o
gcc.link bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/node
bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:315: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)':
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:34: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::thread_info>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:48: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::strand_service::strand_impl, unsigned char>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:48: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    "g++"    -o "bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/node" -Wl,--start-group "bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/main.o"  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic  -Wl,--end-group -g 


...failed gcc.link bin/gcc-4.7.0/debug/node...
...failed updating 1 target...
...updated 1 target...
```

It seems that bjam correctly find the header, but not the libs.
So I tried to tell bjam where to find boost :

Jamfile :

```
use-project /boost : /usr/lib/boost ;

exe node
    : main.cpp
      /boost//system
    ;
```

But bjam will now produce :

```
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:270: in find-jamfile from module project
error: Unable to load Jamfile.
error: Could not find a Jamfile in directory '/usr/lib/boost'.
error: Attempted to find it with pattern '[Bb]uild.jam [Jj]amfile.v2 [Jj]amfile [Jj]amfile.jam'.
error: Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:290: in load-jamfile from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:68: in project.load from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:718: in project.use from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:94: in load-used-projects from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:79: in load from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/build/project.jam:170: in project.find from module project
/usr/share/boost-build/build-system.jam:248: in load from module build-system
/usr/share/boost-build/kernel/modules.jam:261: in import from module modules
/usr/share/boost-build/kernel/bootstrap.jam:132: in boost-build from module
/usr/share/boost-build/boost-build.jam:1: in module scope from module
```

It unerstand that bjam want to rebuild boost, that's why it's looking for a Jamfile in `/usr/lib/boost`.

Is there anything missing ?
How could I tell bjam where are the missing libs to link against ?

Some times ago, I used

```
LINKLIBS = -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem ;
```

But I don't know how to translate this for Boost.build v2.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution.
I expected `<linkflags>` to be able to take more than one lib, but I was wrong.

Here is the fix, I changed my Jamfile to :

```
exe node
: main.cpp
: <linkflags>-lpthread
  <linkflags>-lboost_system
;
```